# How to pass value in session at the controller to the view blade PHP laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, laravel

I have one session inside the controller that carried the data from previous page. Currently, I want to view the data inside the session at the view.blade.php. Or, do I need to create any database query inside the controller?

But, the error that I got is:

```
Undefined variable: user in view.blade.php
```

Here is the controller.

```php
public function policyDownload(Request $request)
{
    $user = \Session::get('plans');
    return view('public.policy');
}
```

Here is the view blade php.

```php
<div class="row mb-2 mt-2">
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <b>
            <h5><b>TAKAFUL CERTIFICATE</b></h5>
        </b><br />
        <b>
            <h6><b>Person Covered</b></h6>
        </b>

        {{ strtoupper($user->name) }} ( {{ $user->nric }} ) <br />
        {{ strtoupper($user->address) }} <br />
        {{ strtoupper($user->address2) }} <br />
        {{ strtoupper($user->postcode) }} {{ strtoupper($user->city) }},
        {{ strtoupper($user->state) }} <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: This is dd($user) output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $data['user'] = \Session::get('plans');
      return view('admin.facts.index', compact('data'));
```

Your style

```
 $user = \Session::get('plans');
      return view('admin.facts.index', compact('user'));
```

Comment: I already try it. It seems I got this error " Trying to get property 'name' of non-object ". What does it means? @gorkhali

Comment: remove all $user->nric  to $user['nric'] is this niric is your database field? $user->name change to $user['name']

Comment: Yup this NRIC is in my database. Still didn't work because it shows this error "Undefined index: name"

Comment: Your key is different dd($user) did not returns name key. Just remove all and print one $user['plan'] then yo got your value. Or dd in views and add image response.

Comment: It returns null value. How to use the session actually? To get the database using the session?

Comment: Ok it means your data is null. To set session Session::put('variableName', $value); To get session data Session::get('variableName');.